# Automated choosing certificate in Firefox + Firefox Driver Config proxy setting in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, jmeter

I'm making Selenium scripts and also Jmeter scripts on our web application and in Jmeter I use WebDriver Sampler there as well.

Problem 1:
I havent found any solution how to automate choosing certificate in Firefox. On our login page there is necassary to choose a certificate after sending credentials. This window occures:
[image: ![User Identification Request window]

In Chrome I handled it by this: https://gist.github.com/IngussNeilands/3bbbb7d78954c85e2e988cf3bfec7caa . Is there some similar solution for Firefox as well?

Problem 2:

When I run the script in Jmeter in Firefox, there is Firefox Driver Config. It has a tab called Proxy:
[image: tab proxy]

The problem is, that I need to use a proxy server to access our website. Unfortunatelly options "Auto-detect proxy settings for this network" or "Use system proxy settings" doesnt work for me. And when I choose "manual proxy configuration", the fields remains dumb and read-only. In Chrome Driver Config this works... Is it a known bug or what is wrong?

I'd appreciate any advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you will need to use a [custom firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles) for this
2. It looks like a bug, it worth reporting it via [JMeter Plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

In the meantime you can switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and instantiate FirefoxDriver manually using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), check [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) for code snippets, the ones in `Java` will work fine with Groovy.